# Imperfection module and base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In EGA $\text{IV}_4$ 0.20.6 the module of imperfection $\Upsilon_{C/B/A}$ associated to maps $A\to B\to C$ of rings is defined as the kernel of the map $\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC\to\Omega^1_{C/A}$, so that there is an exact sequence $0\to\Upsilon_{C/B/A}\to\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC\to\Omega^1_{C/A}\to\Omega^1_{C/B}\to0$. This is a functor: given a commutative diagram from $A\to B\to C$ to $A’\to B’\to C’$ we get a commutative diagram of exact sequences. My question is, when $A=A’$ and $C’=B’\otimes_BC$, do we have $\Upsilon_{C’/B’/A}=\Upsilon_{C/B/A}\otimes_CC’$? If not, can anything be said about these two modules of imperfection beyond what is in EGA $\text{IV}_4$ 0.20.6? (I can assume $B/A$, $B’/A$, $C/A$ are all smooth, so that $\Omega^1_{B/A}$, $\Omega^1_{B’/A}$, $\Omega^1_{C/A}$ are projective modules over $B$, $B'$ and $C$, respectively; perhaps what I want can then be obtained by base change for the cotangent complex?)

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma** -- Let $X,Y,Y'$ be smooth over a scheme $S$. Let $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y'\to Y$ be $S$-morphisms and $f':X':=X\times_YY'\to Y'$. Suppose $X'$ is smooth over $S$. Then $(\ker df)\times_XX'$ surjects onto $\ker df'$.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \Upsilon_{C’/B’/A} @>>> \Omega^1_{B’/A}\otimes_{B’}C’ @>>> \Omega^1_{C’/A} @>>> \Omega^1_{C’/B’} @>>> 0 \\
\ @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> \Upsilon_{C/B/A} @>>> \Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC @>>> \Omega^1_{C/A} @>>> \Omega^1_{C/B} @>>> 0 
\end{CD}

**Proof** -- We're in the situation of the question where $B,B’,C,C’$ are all smooth over $A$ and we wish to show that
$\Upsilon_{C/B/A}\otimes_CC'\twoheadrightarrow\Upsilon_{C'/B'/A}$ surjects.
The question is local on $X'$ so we may assume $f$ factors as a closed
immersion followed by a smooth morphism, corresponding to a factorization of
$\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC\to\Omega^1_{C/A}$ as an injection $\rho$ followed
by a surjection. (The injection $\rho$ remains one after base change
to $C$ because fiberwise it is an isomorphism onto a direct factor
(EGA $\text{IV}_4$ 17.11.1).) We analyze first the case of a closed
immersion, so suppose $f$ is a closed immersion. Letting
$I=\ker(B\twoheadrightarrow C)$ and $J=\ker(B'\twoheadrightarrow C')$, we
have that $\Upsilon_{C/B/A}=I/I^2$ and $\Upsilon_{C'/B'/A}=J/J^2$
(EGA $\text{IV}_4$ 17.12.1). As $I\otimes_BB'\twoheadrightarrow J$ surjects,
$I/I^2\otimes_BB'=I/I^2\otimes_CC'\twoheadrightarrow J/J^2$ does too.

Now we've supposed that the map $B\to C$ factors as
$B\to D\twoheadrightarrow C$ with $B\to D$ smooth and
$D\twoheadrightarrow C$ a surjection.
\begin{CD}
\Omega^1_{B’/A}\otimes_{B’}C’@>{\rho’}>>\Omega^1_{D’/A}\otimes_{D’}C’@>>>\Omega^1_{C’/A} \\
@AAA @AAA @AAA \\
\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC@>{\rho}>>\Omega^1_{D/A}\otimes_{D}C’@>>>\Omega^1_{C/A}
\end{CD}
(Here, the maps $\rho,\rho’$ are injections and the other maps are surjections.)
Clearly $\Upsilon_{C/B/A}=\rho^{-1}(\Upsilon_{C/D/A})$ and as
just seen $\Upsilon_{C/D/A}\otimes_CC'\twoheadrightarrow
\Upsilon_{C'/D'/A}$ surjects. Fiberwise, $\rho$ and $\rho'$
are isomorphisms onto direct factors (EGA $\text{IV}_4$ 17.11.1) with
isomorphic complements: indeed, the sequences
\begin{CD}
0@>>>\Omega^1_{B’/A}\otimes_{B’}D’@>>>\Omega^1_{D’/A}@>>>\Omega^1_{D’/B’}@>>>0 \\
\ @AAA @AAA @AAA \\
0@>>>\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_{B}D@>>>\Omega^1_{D/A}@>>>\Omega^1_{D/B}@>>>0
\end{CD}
are exact and remain so after base change, and
$\Omega^1_{D/B}\otimes_DD'\xrightarrow\sim\Omega^1_{D'/B'}$.
In other words, if $y\in U\subset X'$ with image $x\in X$ and
$\tau'\in(\ker df')_y$, then $\rho'(\tau')$ belongs to
$(\Upsilon_{C'/D'/A})_y$ and also belongs to the direct factor
$\rho'(\Omega^1_{B'/A}\otimes_BC')_y$ of
$(\Omega^1_{D'/A}\otimes_{D'}C')_y$.
As $\Upsilon_{C/D/A}\otimes_CC'\twoheadrightarrow\Upsilon_{C'/D'/A}$
surjects, we can find $\tau\in(\Upsilon_{C/D/A}\otimes_CC')_y$ mapping to
$\rho'(\tau')$, and necessarily $\tau\in\rho(\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC')_y$.
Therefore $\tau'$ is in the image of
$(\Upsilon_{C/B/A}\otimes_CC')_y\to(\Omega^1_{B/A}\otimes_BC')_y
\to(\Omega^1_{B'/A}\otimes_{B'}C')_y$, as desired.

The fiberwise picture is clear: picking a point $y\in X'$ as above, we get a
map of vector spaces
$V_{Y'}=(\Omega^1_{Y'/S})_{f'(y)}\otimes_{\mathcal O_{Y',f'(y)}}k(y)\to V_{X'}=(\Omega^1_{X'/S})_y\otimes_{\mathcal O_{X',y}}k(y)$
fitting into a commutative diagram of $k(y)$-vector spaces
\begin{CD}
V_{Y’}@>>>V_{D’}@>{a’}>>V_{X’} \\
@AAA @AAA @AAA \\
V_Y@>>>V_D@>{a}>>V_X
\end{CD}
where $V_D=V_Y\oplus W$ and $V_{D'}=V_{Y'}\oplus W$. Moreover, $\ker a$
surjects onto $\ker a'$, so if $\tau'\in\ker a'\cap V_{Y'}$, we can find a
$\tau\in\ker a\cap V_Y$ mapping to $\tau'$.